# Using xmlpipe2 with Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I'm attempting to load large amounts of data directly into Sphinx from Mongo; and currently the best method I've found has been using xmlpipe2.

I'm wondering however if there are ways to just do updates to the dataset, as a full reindex of hundreds of thousands of records can take a while and be a bit intensive on the system.

Is there a better way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main plus delta scheme. When all the updates goes to separate smaller index as described here:

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#delta-updates

Comment: Isn't this limited to using only using SQL? I'm not interacting at all with sql.  Is there another way to get this to work?

Comment: You can use distributed index with any source. XML pipe is the way how Sphinx building index, main+delta is the way how Sphinx searching it. You even can combine indexes from different sources if you need to.

Comment: No its not limited to SQL. The same 'methodoly' can work with xmlpipe. You just need a second xmlpipe script that only returns the updated records. It would have to maintain somewhere a pointer/counter that is updated by the main xmlpipe script. You just need all the logic that is implemeneted using sql-queries in the example, to be implemented inside your xmlpipe  scripts

Comment: @barryhunter excellent, I see what you mean.  Thank you very much for the help with understanding that! This is going to significantly quicken my updates.